# How to adjust height of bar percentage label on top of bar rather than on?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
relationship_bw_Polattrev_fbse_Percent_plot <- ggplot(data = anes_sm, aes(x = polattrev_recoded, fill = fbse_recoded)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),
           position = "dodge") + 
  geom_text(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), 
                label = paste0(prop.table(..count..) * 100, '%')), 
            stat = 'count', 
            position = position_dodge(.9), 
            size = 5)+ 
  labs(x = 'Amount of attention towards politics and govt', 
       y = 'Frequency Percent',
       title = 'Relationship between attention to politics and government and if sees politics online', fill='Sees POL on FB')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))+
  theme_bw()
```

This is my current script for this figure but the percentage label for each graph is on the bar rather than above which I want. How do I do this?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aevl.png

Comment: Try with `geom_text(..., vjust = 0)` or vjust = -.1 value to add some "padding".

Comment: Hi and thanks. Does this go inside geom_text(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..),